# How to change prop of Material UIs Button component based on screen size breakpoint when using a class component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, media-queries

Im using Material UI's Button component and would like to conditionally determine the variant of the button. That is, on screens medium and up, the variant should be 'outlined' and when the screen is smaller than medium, the variant type should be none. I am using a class component. I have done my research to see what others have done. I have seen the method of using useMediaQuery method but that would require me to change the component to a functional component. Im not sure if I know if that is a good idea because the component is rather a large one and that means will be a bit confusing to convert. I also tried using a ternary operator like this:

```
const variantType = theme.breakpoints.down("md") ? '' : 'outline';

<Button variant={variantType}>
       Food Pick
 </Button>
```

But this didnt do the job. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

```
Update: Here is my code after trying to wrap the component but in a functional component but its giving an error:
```

[image]

```
import { withStyles, withTheme, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { PulseLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';



const styles = theme => ({
  beta: {
    height: '17px',
    fontSize: '12px',
    marginLeft: '10px'
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    maxHeight: '400px',
    minHeight: '300px',
    overflowY: 'auto'
  },
  progressContainer: {
    height: '350px',
  },
  modalDescription: {
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    marginTop: '20px',
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: '20px',
    marginLeft: '10px',
    marginRight: '10px',
  },
  smartSuggestContainer: {
    textAlign: 'right',
    paddingRight: '35px',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      margin: '40px 0'
    },
  },
});

export default function MyComponentWrapper({ ...rest }) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const mediumScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));
  return <FoodDescriptions {...rest} mediumScreen={mediumScreen} />;
}

class FoodDescriptions extends Component {
  static PAGE_SIZE = 25;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showFoodDescriptionsModal: false,
      dataLoaded: false,
      data: [],
      page: 0,
      sortBy: 'return',
      sortDir: 'desc',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeypress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeypress);
  }

  fetchData = async (page, sortBy, sortDir) => {
    const { currentBotId } = this.props;
    const offset = page * FoodDescriptions.PAGE_SIZE;
    const data = await getFoodDescriptions(currentBotId, sortBy, sortDir, FoodDescriptions.PAGE_SIZE, offset);
    this.setState({
      dataLoaded: true,
      data,
    });
  };

  handleKeypress = (e) => {
    const { showSnartConfigsModal } = this.state;
    const { key } = e;
    if (key === 'Escape' && showSnartConfigsModal) {
      this.closeModal();
    }
  };

  applyConfig = (botId, params) => {
    const { updateConfig, botConfig, actions } = this.props;
    updateConfig({ name: botConfig.name, config: Object.assign(botConfig.config, params) });
    this.closeModal();
    actions.showNotification({ data: 'Configuration has been applied' });
  };

  openModal = () => {
    const { page, sortBy, sortDir } = this.state;
    this.fetchData(page, sortBy, sortDir);
    this.setState({
      showFoodDescriptionsModal: true,
    });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      showFoodDescriptionsModal: false,
    });
  };

  changePage = (page) => {
    const { sortBy, sortDir } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      page,
      dataLoaded: false
    }, () => this.fetchData(page, sortBy, sortDir));
  };

  changeSortBy = (sortBy) => {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring */
    let sortDir = this.state.sortDir;
    if (sortBy === this.state.sortBy) {
      sortDir = (this.state.sortDir === 'desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    }
    this.setState({
      sortBy,
      sortDir,
      dataLoaded: false,
    }, () => this.fetchData(this.state.page, sortBy, sortDir));
  };

  renderEmptyState() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center" className={classes.progressContainer}>
        <Typography className={classes.noCoinsText}>No configurations found</Typography>
      </Grid>
    );
  }

  renderLoader() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center" className={classes.progressContainer}>
        <PulseLoader size={6} color="#52B0B0" loading />
      </Grid>
    );
  }

  renderTable() {
    const { data, page } = this.state;
    return (
      <StrategiesTable
        strategies={data}
        onClickCopy={this.applyConfig}
        page={page}
        changePage={this.changePage}
        sortBy={this.changeSortBy} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const {
      classes, userFeatures, botConfig, theme
    } = this.props;
    const { showFoodDescriptionsModal, dataLoaded } = this.state;

    if (!botConfig) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className={classes.smartSuggestContainer}>
          <Button
            name="discoverConfigs"
            variant={theme.breakpoints.down(600) ? '' : 'outlined'}
            color="primary"
            size="small"
            disabled={!userFeatures['smart_suggest_backtests'.toUpperCase()] || botConfig.status.toLowerCase() === STATUSES.RUNNING}
            onClick={this.openModal}>
           
            Food Buy
          </Button>
          </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}



function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    userFeatures: state.global.paywall.features,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatcher) {
  return {
    actions: {
      ...bindActionCreators({
        showNotification,
      }, dispatcher)
    }
  };
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withTheme()(withStyles(styles)(FoodDescriptions)));
```

Comment: You don't have to convert the whole component. Just create a new component to wrap the button that takes care of this aspect and use that component from within your class component.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have attempted it but am getting an error. Can you review my code and see if it is same as what you meant? Thanks! @RyanCogswell

Comment: Please share a simplified version of the relevant code in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a functional component using useMediaQuery and returning the responsive Button ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I have attempted your suggestion but am getting an error. I also updated the post with my code